# When opening Terminal posts export 'not a valid identifier' for Python source activate

Tags: python, terminal, bash

I'm running Mac OS X v10.9.2. When I log onto my terminal I'm immediately greeted by the following:

```
Last login: Wed May 14 22:45:00 on ttys007
-bash: export: `/Users/NabilKaz/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate': not a valid identifier
```

I use Enthought Canopy and I'm guessing it's activating a Python virtual environment?

Here are the contents of my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"L_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /Users/NabilKaz/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate


[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

# Added by Canopy installer on 2014-02-19
# VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT can be set to '' to make bashprompt show that Canopy is active, otherwise 1
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /Users/NabilKaz/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate
```

Comment: Put a space before `L_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1`  in export line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"L_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /Users/NabilKaz/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate
```

Should be

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
L_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /Users/NabilKaz/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate
```